# Python. Transform str('+') to mathematical operation

Tags: python, eval

How transform str('+') to mathematical operation?
For example:

```
a = [0,1,2] # or a = ['0','1','2']
b = ['+','-','*']
c = int(a[0]+b[0]+a[1])
```

In other words, how transform `str('-1*2')` to `int()`, without `for i in c: if i == '+': ...`
Thanks.

Comment: c = eval(a[0]+b[0]+a[1])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i thin you're looking for eval(), but i advice to use something else...
however,

```
>>> eval('-1*2')
-2
```

eval 'executes' the string you pass to it, like code. so it's quite dangerous for security, especially if the parameters are user input...

in this case i suggest to use parsing library, such as ply http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/
that for such thing is really simple to use and very effective :)

Comment: using a full implementation of lex/yacc is almost certainly overkill for this.

Comment: maybe...but if he has to face this problem several time in his code, maybe with just a little bit more of operations, it's better to create a simple module or a class and pass the code to it...or he can implement his own parser ;)   ( i really hate  eval )

Comment: I too strongly distrust eval but a parser isn't necessary in this case: a filter on the allowed characters suffices. That also has the advantage of being less error prone and hence more secure. Also a module and classes are probably overkill as well - a simple function should work fine.

Comment: uhm...yeah, maybe in this case too much OOP ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the operator module:

```
import operator as op
#Create a mapping between the string and the operator:
ops = {'+': op.add, '-': op.sub, '*': op.mul}

a = [0,1,2]
b = ['+','-','*']

#use the mapping
c = ops[b[0]](a[0], a[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

If your math expressions will fit Python syntax but you are skeered of eval (you should be) you can look into python's `ast` module ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#module-ast)).  It will parse the expression into an abstract syntax tree you can iterate over.  You can evaluate a limited subset of Python and throw errors if you encounter anything outside your expression grammar.

Comment: Using the `ast` module is a good idea and you don't even have to parse the expression if you use the `ast.literal_eval()` [helper function](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast-helpers). From the docs: "This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself." Of course, this your input must be a string containing a valid Python expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use eval like everyone else is saying but filter it first.

```
>>> s = '1 + 12 / 2 - 12*31'
>>> allowed = set(' 1234567890()+-/*\\')
>>> if allowed.issuperset(s):
...     eval(s)
... 
-365
```

Comment: +1. It's probably worth noting that even this isn't totally safe: for example, what happens if the input is `'99 ** 99 ** 99 ** 99 ** 99 ** 99 ** 99'`?  But I don't see any vulnerabilities with this approach that could be avoided by parsing the input; either way I think you'd have to have CPU/memory usage limits in place.  Unless you actually analyzed the parsed formula for various edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Answer (score 0):

Use eval:

```
> eval(str('-1*2'))
> -2
```

Answer (score 0):

Dett,

A Simple eval on the whole string... However be aware that if the user inputs the string, eval is risky, unless you do some parsing first

```
x = '-1*2'
y = eval(x)
```

y will then be the integer value.